# Invoke client side button click from server event (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, server-side, simplemodal

I'am building an asp.net application that have a gridview inside an update pannel.

In this grid, I added a command field that raise a server event to fill fields on my modal popup hiden div section.

Off course, once filled, I want to display the modal popup to the user.

my issue is : how do I make that popup visible?

I use http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

the same way it work in the sample, the modal work well when I click on a client side link, but how may I invoke the show event from a server side even with asp.net (VB or C#)?

I am totally new to JQuery and AJAX, thanks for your help

Steph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to command button's click handler method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Control)sender, sender.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
    string.Format("$('#{0}').modal();", modalDiv.ClientID ), true);
```